# Control windows or file explorer to upload files in protractor

Tags: protractor

I am trying to upload files in my protractor E2E test. Googling a bit I ended up using robotJS. 
Unfortunately , the installation of `robotJS` is failing. 
Is there any other way to get my files uploaded.

Steps:

1. Click on upload button
2. File explorer opens.
3. Enter the path
4. click on upload.

I tried using FileDetector and below is the code:

```
let fileToUpload = 'testfolder';
let absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
await browser.setFileDetector(new remote.FileDetector());
$('input[type="file"]').sendKeys(absolutePath);
```

This doesn't really pass or search for the absolute path. 
What is missing here ?

Comment: Do you need to interact with the file explorer window or would by-passing it all together work for you?

Comment: If by bypassing works I can still upload files then its well and good. If not , handling the file exlorer window should do.

Comment: As mentioned , I wanted to try robotJS but it seems to have a bug, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If you have folder e2e with 2 folders: folder tests containing your test and folder images containing testFile, try this:

```
const filePath = '../images/testFile';
const absolutePath = require('path').resolve(__dirname, filePath);
$('input[type="file"]').sendKeys(absolutePath);
```

Comment: Thanks. But the testfolder only contains the files that I want to upload

Comment: I've only mentioned this structure so that you'll know what should filePath represent... if test and files are in the same folder, you might try `const filePath = './testFile';` I had troubles previously when I wrote just a fileName ..