# Upload file in test E2E with Protractor

Tags: angular, protractor, node-modules

In my test, I have a button which is used to browse my disc and select a file.

I want to use `function(el: WebElement)`, but I have an error:

```
import { ElementFinder, browser, by, element } from 'protractor';
```

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

My code in **fic_test.js**:

```
it("Upload file",function(){
        let filePath = "../../../PJ/a.jpg";
        let fpath = path.resolve(__dirname,filePath);     
        browser.get("...");
        browser.sleep(5000);
        browser.findElement(by.xpath('//button[contains(.," Télécharger un autre document ")]')).then(function(el: WebElement){
            browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",el);
            el.sendKeys(fpath);
        });
```

**Files in my project :**

- conf/conf.js
- tests/fic_test.js

Answer (score 0):

I think you sendKeys to the element with input tag, at least, that's the only way it worked for me, and from your xpath I don't think you're sending fpath to the right element.
Also, take a look at [my reply to a similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56151063/control-windows-or-file-explorer-to-upload-files-in-protractor/56151389#56151389), it may be of help

UPDATE in answer to your comment:
Sorry, I used this code where I work, so sharing the whole of it is a no go.
This is how I'd write the test you mentioned in your question:

```
const EC = ExpectedConditions;

it('Upload file', () => {
 const filePath = '../../../PJ/a.jpg';
 const absolutePath = require('path').resolve(__dirname, filePath);
  browser.get("...");
  // maybe add here a little wait
  browser.wait(EC.presenceOf($('cssSelector-of-ur-input-el')), 5000, 'ERROR: Input el. not found');
  $('cssSelector-of-ur-input-el').sendKeys(absolutePath);
});
```

I found no real need to scroll the page to the element being used, since its presence was the only thing protractor needed... hope it helps :)

Comment: I saw your answer in the other post but it's still KO. Can you show your complete code plz? for testing